# What parameters should I adjust in ggplot if my axis titles are being clipped?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

Fairly specific question here, but it may help others who are having similar issues.

I have some simple data:

```
Y = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10, 0.13, 0.17, 0.17, 0.21, 0.22,   
0.35, 0.47, 0.51, 0.53, 0.54, 0.65, 0.78)  
X = c(0.45, 0.26, 0.35, 0.22, 0.37, 0.09, 0.27, 0.51, 0.39, 0.37, 0.37, 0.27, 0.51, 0.36, 
0.44, 0.49, 0.63, 0.49, 0.71, 0.56, 0.67)
self1 = data.frame(X, Y)
```

I also have a simple custom ggplot theme:

```
plot.theme = theme(axis.text = element_text(size=26), axis.title=element_text(size=28),  
plot.title=element_text(size=36, margin=margin(0,0,20,0)), panel.grid.minor
= element_blank(), plot.margin=unit(c(0.1,0.25,0.5,0.85), "cm"), axis.title.y = 
element_text(margin=margin(0,15,0,0)), panel.border = element_rect(color="black", fill=NA,
size=2), axis.ticks = element_blank(), legend.title = element_text(size=26), legend.text = 
element_text(size=18))
```

When I plot a scatterplot of the data with marginal histograms:

```
bing = ggplot(self1, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point(size=3) + 
         geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=F, color="black") + 
         plot.theme +
         ylab("Observed selfing rate") + 
         xlab("Observed crossing rate") + 
         geom_vline(xintercept = 0.42, linetype="longdash") + 
         geom_hline(yintercept = 0.25, linetype="longdash")   

ggExtra::ggMarginal(bing, type = "histogram", bins=6, size=10)
```

Everything looks great, except that the "g" in "Observed crossing rate" is getting cut off at the bottom of the graph. I have tried fidgeting with every theme parameter I can think of, and I've also tried adjusting several of the arguments to `ggMarginal`, but I have yet to find the one I need to change to get everything to stay inside the plot area. Can anyone help me out? I suspect the issue ultimately lies with the way ggMarginal is auto-adjusting the sizes of various theme parameters, but that's just a hunch.

Comment: Your data are posted in a very-difficult-to-use form. Please repost the data sample by pasting into your question the output of `dput(self1)`.

Comment: I know it's not clear from the SO FAQ, but the SO admins don't charge extra for carriage returns and your original posting of `X` & `Y` was not valid R syntax. If you really want folks to assist you, you should probably make it easier for them to do so.

Comment: Hello @eipi10, I'm not clear on how dput() works. I have added a line of code that should at least make the object `self1` correctly now. @hrbmstr, I'm afraid I don't know what a carriage return is, but I will try to edit the post to fix it. That said, when I copy and paste my code from above into R, it runs just fine for me.

Comment: Posting `X` and `Y` with commas was a big improvement. Now they can just be pasted into an R script. The best way to provide data is by either creating sample data as you've now done or pasting in the output of `dput(self1)`. Then the data frame can be copied and pasted into an R session and be exactly the same as the data you used in your code.

Comment: Also, you don't need `cbind`. You can just do `self1=data.frame(X,Y)`

Comment: Aha excellent. Thanks @eipi10. That's a cool feature. The post should be formatted properly now. Let me know if there's anything else to adjust.

Comment: `data.frame`, not `as.data.frame`. Also, regarding formatting, you should put line breaks in the code for `plot.theme` and `bing` so that you can see all the code without scrolling.

Comment: @eipi10, is this ok now? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, the idea is to have rational line-breaks, like the way code would be formatted in a script file, so that it's easy to read. See my edits to your `bing` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `g` is your plot, you can do `g$vp = grid::viewport(height=0.9, width=0.9)` before drawing it (print or grid.draw)

Comment: Very nice, basic solution. This is a very handy thing to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to change the plot margins on the object returned by `ggMarginal`. So, until someone comes along with a better solution, you can modify the code in the `ggMarginal` function itself. Here's how:

1. Type `ggMarginal` in the console. This will print the code of `ggMarginal`. Paste this code into a script window. Give this function a new name, like `my_ggMarginal = [all the ggMarginal code you just pasted in]`.
2. Find the following line inside this function:

   ```
   p <- p + ggplot2::theme(plot.margin = grid::unit(c(0, 0, 
                                              0, 0), "null"))
   ```

   and change it to this:

   ```
   p <- p + ggplot2::theme(plot.margin = grid::unit(c(0, 0, 
                                              1, 0), "lines"))
   ```
3. Run the code for the new function you just created so that `my_ggMarginal` will be available in your current workspace.
4. Run your new function on `bing`:

   ```
   my_ggMarginal(bing, type = "histogram", bins=6, size=10)
   ```

Comment: Very clever solution. Should have thought about creating a wrapper, but might not have been feeling brave enough. 1 was too much for me, but it turned out that 0.02 was just right, and didn't distort the graph at all. Thanks! I will give you the check if no one has a more direct solution.